# How to call a method from main window class that doesn't determined in it?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, datagrid, objectdataprovider

I've got a method in MainWindow class. I need to call a method that is situating in it. The other class is using for datagrid [binding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples#introduction) so I dont know its name.

I've got http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples/classdiagram_small.png class inheritance. I use it to modify data in datagrid. I've got 1 more datagrid that has related data(I use grids to show DB tables). I need to call datagrid by its name to change its itemsource. I can do it from mainfrom class. This class can see datagrid's name but first datagrid cant see other datagrid

Comment: Sounds like you want to use either a delegate or an event, but there isn't enough detail to really say much more.

Comment: See the question. I have just changed it a little

Comment: post the relevant code

Comment: it sounds like Servi is correct. Yeah, I think I must use delegate function